# How to extract boot.img?

Tags: filesystems, boot, android

I am trying to see the content in a `boot.img` file from an Android image.

I googled and found [this article](http://javigon.com/2012/09/04/mount-unmount-android-system-images/) to extract `system.img`, but it doesn't work for `boot.img`. When trying to do this for `boot.img`, it is showing the following:

```
Invalid sparse file format at header magi
Failed to read sparse file
```

Is `simg2img` used only for extracting `system.img`?

1. If so, Is there any other method to extract `boot.img`?
2. If not, what is the problem for not extracting `boot.img`?

Comment: please identify the specific linux distribution and the kernel version.

Comment: There a similar question on Android.SE site: [How to unpack and edit `boot.img` for ROM porting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69954/107603)

Comment: Check the answer from @cfig. The other ones are outdated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`boot.img` is a small(ish) file that contain two main parts.

- kernel (important for android)
- ramdisk (a core set of instruction & binaries)

##### Unpack `boot.img`:

It contains the following steps:

1. Download the tool using

   ```shell
   wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/android-serialport-api/android_bootimg_tools.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the file using

   ```shell
   tar xvzf android_bootimg_tools.tar.gz
   ```

   It contains two binaries:

   - `unpackbootimg`
   - `mkbootimg`
3. Then execute

   ```shell
   ./unpackbootimg -i <filename.img> -o <output_directory>
   ```

   The `output_directory` will contain:

   - `boot.img-zImage` (kernel)
   - `boot.img-ramdisk.gz` (ramdisk)

We can extract the ramdisk also, using the following command

```shell
gunzip -c boot.img-ramdisk.gz | cpio -i
```

After changing the files, we can again pack those files as `boot.img` using `mkbootimg`

Comment: I am getting error at third step please help me...the terminal says unpackbootimg command not found

Comment: Getting the same error for step 3 on Mint 17 here. Tried running them by sudo and after chmod 755 to no avail.

Comment: In step 3, make sure `output_path` already exists, otherwise `unpackbootimg` will segfault.

Comment: The link for the tool is dead.

Comment: Just clone the code from github: https://github.com/osm0sis/mkbootimg

Comment: Fix for: "unpackbootimg command not found", you are running 32bit binary on a 64 bit machine without 32bit dependencies. Install them with "apt-get install gcc-multilib"

Comment: do I need to connect it in fastboot mode, or just simply connect?

Comment: I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I tried when I was connecting using adb, then I tried in fastboot mode after I started `adb reboot bootloader`. I also tried to unlock OEM in DevTools, and I still get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 10):

Install  [`abootimg`](https://gitlab.com/ajs124/abootimg) (available as a package, for example in [Debian/Ubuntu](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/abootimg) and [openSUSE](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Factory/abootimg)).

To extract `(boot|recovery).img`:

```
$ abootimg -x (boot|recovery).img
$ ls
boot.img  bootimg.cfg  initrd.img  zImage
```

To repack `(boot|recovery).img` after modifying one of `bootimg.cfg`, `zImage` or `initrd.img`:

```
abootimg --create (boot|recovery).img -f bootimg.cfg -k zImage -r initrd.img
```

Comment: This project is not maintained and did not work with my boot.img file, however the answer from @cfig worked.

Answer (score 6):

`boot.img` is not a compressed filesystem image like `system.img`. It is read by the bootloader, and contains little more than a kernel image and a ramdisk image.

Some binary distribution ship the kernel and ramdisk images separately. In that case you don't need to do anything with `boot.img`, just regenerate a new one with `mkbootimg`.

If you need to extract information from a `boot.img`, try [`split_bootimg`](http://www.enck.org/tools/split_bootimg_pl.txt) (by [William Enck](http://www.enck.org/tools.html), via [the Android wiki](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Unpack%2C_Edit%2C_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images)).

Comment: The link to `split_bootimg` is no longer valid.

Comment: @NathanOsman Replaced by a link to the copy on William Enck's page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following tool to extract and re-pack Android boot image

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cfig/Android_boot_image_editor.git
```

copy your boot.img to the cloned git repository. Run:

```
$ ./gradlew unpack
```

First time run will need to download necessary libs from internet, be patient. 
You can get the contents at "build/unzip_boot/", like this:

```
build/unzip_boot/
├── bootimg.json (boot image info)
├── kernel
├── second (2nd bootloader, if exists)
├── boot.img.avb.json (AVB only)
└── root
```

Comment: This is the answer, as this code and project is current and maintained.

Comment: It no longer works for arm64, but I made an issue.